# ActionScript 3 keyboard event not firing after button click

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, keyboard-events

I'm building a simple game in which you control the character with W A S D keys. When you die, you go to another frame that says you died and has a button to play the game again. When I click the button, it goes to the frame 1 again, but the keyboard events don't work unless I click once more on the screen. How can I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question seems a bit specific to your code, do you remove and then add again the listeners?

Comment: I remove the enter frame listener when the character dies but I don't remove the key listener

Comment: How are you adding the key listeners

Answer (score 0):

On your frame1 try adding an active listiner to set the focus:

```
activate="this.setFocus()"
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get your question clearly. If once you click on that button it is working correctly right. If the way which i have understood is correct there might be problem on  your looping or condition. please let me know your coding here,  I will try to resolve. else check yourself the looping or condition on the frame1 or where you wrote your keybord  event listener.   I hope it will be usefull else please let me know i will give you another solution.